# "Tidy" vs "Neat"

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, word-meaning, word-difference

According to the dictionary definitions:

> **Tidy:** 
>   having everything ordered and arranged in the right place, or liking to keep things like this.
>
> **Neat:** 
>  
>   tidy, with everything in its place.

Please let me know how the following sentences differ in meaning?

> 1) She likes everything **neat** and **tidy**.
>
> 2)
>   - Your house is always very **clean and tidy**. How do you manage it? 
>   - Your house is always very **clean and neat**. How do you manage it?
>
> 3) 
>   - My roommate is not very **tidy**. 
>   - My roommate is not very **neat**.

I think they both mean the same thing and "tidy" is a subset of "neat". In the manner that something that is "neat" can be "tidy" too, but something that is tidy cannot always be neat. However, I cannot understand their true meanings.

Answer (score 4):

In the ordinary description you'd say they were synonyms, but to delve a little into their history:

- **neat** is originally from French *net* (clean) and has a sense of "unadulterated", "elegant", "well proportioned".  In the US (I'd guess in 50s) it has the sense of "cool" ("a neat car", "a neat piece of machinery.")
- **tidy** is originally from Old English *tid* (time) and has a sense of "timely", "ordered", "good".  Still in Scotland you'll hear "a tidy sum" = "a good amount of money", "a tidy step" = "good healthy distance".

In UK we very frequently use **neat and tidy** as a phrase just for emphasis.